# How to switch sprite animation with cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have two animations of a goalkeeper with two different states (with ball and without ball). After keeper jumps I want to switch to a different action but I want to stay at the same frame index.

I mean if goalkeeper collides with the ball in the frame 19, the second action should start at frame 19 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure if I completely understand what your trying to do but I can help you with that action. If you want to run a check every frame you should do somethng like this

At the end of your scenes init method add:

` [self schedule: @selector(tick:) interval: 0.3f];

**-(void)tick:(ccTime) dt {**
                                                                                                                             **if(CGRectIntersectsRect(goalKeeper.textureRect, ball.textureRect) {
     [goalKeeper stopAction: myAction];** //where myAction is previously defined
}     //now you can start the new action because you're using a timer, it'll be the same frame

That should do it. I hope that helps, if I still didn't quite answer your question feel free to clarify what in more vivid what exactly you're going for.                                                        `

Comment: let me clarify a little bit more, here in "myAction", let's say I have 100 frame animation. I also have a "newAction" which has also 100 frames. when collision happens, like in your example. I would like to stop "myAction" (let's assume it is on it's 20th frame), and start "newAction", but the problem is "newAction" should start from its 20th frame.

Comment: Ohhhhh! So basically what you're trying to do is complete the rest of the animation with him holding the ball. I'm with you now, I think I have the perfect solution but you never told me if it is a spritesheet you're using.

Comment: actually I am using [CCSpriteFrameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile].

Comment: Okay well what you want to so is have 2 arrays, one with the ball frames and one without. The trick I would actually use is to have 3 arrays, one being empty. When that condition is meant, get the current frame of your animation and go to array #2 and copy the frames from that position to the end into your new array, and jus empty it when you're gone so you can reuse it. That's one way to do it and it shouldn't be excessive on memory considering the images are cached. Hope this helps, OR just have 2 sprites, one that holds the ball and one that doesn't.And just use the same trick as the former